# How to append to a div?

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden placeholder in my html:

```
<div id="backup_add" class="hidden"></div>
```

Now in the javascript I have a `<tr>` like this:

```
var row = $(add_button_row).closest('form').closest('tr');
```

The moment I try to append the tr to the placeholder as backup, the script breaks. I have no idea why.

```
$('#backup_add').append(row);
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: add_button_row is also a tr. :)

Comment: what is the error !, check the `script` tab in the IE developer tools , or see the console if you are using (ff/chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to append a copy of the row, no the row itself (as it cannot exists in 2 different locations at the same time). And actually tr in a div is not a valid markup.

```
$('#backup_add').append($(row).clone());
```

Comment: yes, it seems cloning it allows me to do that. On top of having tr inside div also made problems so I had to get its children and copy them to the div instead.  Now its working. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are really close, use the jQuery `appendTo()` function: http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

```
$('#backup_add').appendTo(row);
```

This will place your div right after whatever row refers to. Also, if you ever need to add anything before a DOM element you can use the `prependTo` function in the same manner.

Comment: Doesn't he want to append a row to `<div>` but not vice versa?